# How to use overflow-x: hidden on <input type = "number">

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is an example

```
<style type = "text/css">
    .thequoteofpee {
        position: absolute;
        left: 464px;
        top: 362px;
        font-size: 20px;
        width: 420px;
        height: 40px;
        border-color: #00297A;
        border: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        background-color: white;
        text-indent: 10px;
        }
</style>

<body>
<input name = "thequoteofpee" class = "thequoteofpee" type = "quote" placeholder = "Bio"/>
</body>
```

Does anyone know how to make it so the person can only type in 150 characters. And how do you make it so there is like a `text-indent` coming in from the right side so it looks better. Thanks for whoever tries to answer this question!

P.S.
I had nothing to name the class so I named it weirdly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for text-indenting you can use padding instead, thus you can control the four values top, right, bottom and left instead of the one value text-indent offers, just like this:

```
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
```

for limiting maximum length of character use `maxlength="20"` , *Update* use it as an attribute like this

```
<input name = "thequoteofpee" class = "thequoteofpee" type = "quote" placeholder = "Bio" maxlength="20"/>
```

Comment: The `padding` works but the `maxlength` is not working

Comment: You should also use box-sizing: border-box to ensure that the original size is kept; otherwise, you will be adding 20px to the input's width.

Answer (score 2):

Use maxlength for the character limit, and instead of text-indent, you can use padding, which affects all the sides of the input.

```css
.thequoteofpee {
        font-size: 20px;
        width: 420px;
        height: 40px;
        border-color: #00297A;
        border: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        background-color: white;
        padding: 10px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        }
```

```html
<body>
<input name = "thequoteofpee" class = "thequoteofpee" type = "quote" 
    placeholder = "Bio" maxlength="150"/>
</body>
```

Since padding adds to the box's height and width by default, you should also use box-sizing: border-box to ensure that the original height and width are kept. If you only want padding for the left and right sides, use padding-left: 10px and padding-right: 10px instead.

I've taken the liberty of removing the position, left and top attributes for this demo because otherwise it's rather annoying to find the input in the snippet, but believe me, it works just as fine. :-)